# Throw exception to rollback and redirect to another action at the same time

Tags: c#, rollback, aspnetboilerplate, unit-of-work, transactionscope

I am attempting to redirect an action to another one when an exception occurs. In addition, I want to rollback 
 all changes at the same time. Rollbacking data is done by throwing an exception but when we throw an exception, the redirect is not working. (I use a framework (ABP) that handles rollback automatically when an exception is thrown, so there is no "BeginTransaction" and "Commit" etc. in my code.)

When the code runs, it just rollback changes to data and show exception but not redirect.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> action1()
{
    var exception=false;

    try
    {
        await method1();

        return RedirectToAction("Success", "Result");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exception = true;
        return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Result");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (exception == true)
            throw new Exception("1000"); 
    }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> method1()
{
    // Some changes on database
}
```

Comment: You're throwing an exception in the `finally` block so your `RedirectToAction` return value isn't being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABP's [Conventional Unit of Work](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work#conventional-unit-of-work-methods) is scoped around your Controller action `action1`.

You should require a new unit of work that is scoped within your `try` block:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> action1()
{
    try
    {
        using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            await method1();
            uow.Complete();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Success", "Result");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Result");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make `method1` `virtual` and mark it with the `UnitOfWork` attribute:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> action1()
{
    try
    {
        await method1();

        return RedirectToAction("Success", "Result");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Result");
    }
}

[UnitOfWork(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> method1()
{
    // Some changes on database
}
```

Reference: [How to return -1 in catch block (aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#2732)](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2732)

Answer (score 1):

> In addition I want to rollback all changes at same time. Rollbacking data needs throw exception and when we throw an exception, redirect not working.

You can't have a method return a result *and* throw an exception; it's either one or the other.

What you can do is throw an exception - which causes the rollbacks - and then catch it in your action method and return a result:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> action1()
{
  try
  {
    await method1();
    return RedirectToAction("Success", "Result");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Result");
  }
}
```

Comment: Catching an exception is equal by avoiding rollback.

Comment: The exception is thrown from - and propagates out of - `method1`. The rollback system *should* rollback just due to that. But if your custom rollback system requires an exception *thrown from `action1`*, then you'll need to modify your custom rollback system so that it can recognize and handle a specific kind of exception that contains the result to return.